# Maven - Excluding transitive dependency from DependencyManagement

Tags: java, maven

Consider following `pom.xml` using maven `3.6.2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <groupId>bar</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <dependencies>
<!-- #1
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdbi3-jackson2</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- #2
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdbi3-jackson2</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
-->
  </dependencies>

<!-- #3
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbi3-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
-->

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

If you run `mvn dependency:tree | grep databind` you should see:

```
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
```

This is the baseline and establishes `kafka_2.12` uses `jackson-databind:2.10.0`

If you uncomment only comment #1 and re-run, then you should see:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9.3:compile
```

This makes sense to me and tells me `jdbi3-jackson2` uses `jackson-databind:2.9.9.3` and this version is used because it appears *before* `kafka_2.12`

If you uncomment only comment #2 and re-run, then you should see:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
```

This also makes sense to me because `jdbi3-jackson2` now appears *after* `kafka_2.12`

If you uncomment only comment #3 and re-run, then you should see:

```
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9.3:compile
```

I expected `2.10.0` because I am not using anything from the bom (specifically `jdbi3-jackson2`)

Based on almost everything everyone says about boms, I would have thought that their version information would only be used when applying a dependency in the bom

Further, if I add the following *anywhere* in `dependencyManagement` then it goes back to `2.10.0`:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

1. how do I detect this issue (I only found this out because kafka will fail and tell you it requires a specific jackson).  My thought is to write a script/plugin that compares dependency:tree against a 'golden' copy and fail if they differ to at least make people double check their changes when modifying `dependencyManagement`
2. how do I exclude a dependency from `dependencyManagement`?  I have done it with normal dependencies and the same exclusions tag exists for `dependencyManagement`, but nothing I try works.  I would assume the excludes takes effect when you actually use the dependency, but I also thought the version would only take effect when you actually use the dependency as well but that assumption appears to be wrong.
3. because I cannot exclude it, I can force the version via the method above, but why does it work irrespective of the order when it is in `dependencyManagement` unlike where order matters in the normal `dependencies` tag?

Comment: For 1. I recommend to use [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) For 2. You can only exclude direct transitive dependencies. For 3. The algorithm decides based on the nearest definition which means the nearer the dependency is to your project it will be selected.

Comment: If you make this an answer, I can mark it as the solution

Comment: Looks like the JDBI BOM includes tons of transitive dependencies which I think it should not.  Have filed https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/1656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For #1. I recommend to use [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html)
- For #2. You can only exclude direct transitive dependencies.
- For #3. The algorithm decides based on the nearest definition which means the nearer the dependency is to your project it will be selected.

Comment: For #3, is 'nearest' defined as breadth first or depth first or something else?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, BOMs override transitive dependencies. If a dependency somewhere appear in your dependency tree and the BOM specifies a version for it, that version wins, unless:

- You defined the dependency yourself with a different version.
- You added a dependencyManagement entry yourself overriding the value in the BOM.

Also, of course, if BOMs overlap, only one can win.

So if you have `jackson-databind` as a transitive dependency and you have a BOM that includes it, you get the version from the BOM. Unless you make a dependencyManagement entry yourself that overrides the BOM.

Comment: I guess that first part is what I was missing but discovered in my example.  I am still unclear on #3 specifically why order appears to matter when overriding a dependency via the `dependencies` tag and not when doing so in the `dependencyManagement` tag